# Is there a DIN font free alternative?

Tags: font-recommendation, web-safe

I need a websafe alternative to DIN font. It needs to be free for commercial use. Anyone know of a good one?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_1451

Comment: “Barlow” is a good option: https://www.weld.io/weld-font-in-google-fonts/din-vs-barlow

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*The situation has changed since this question was first asked in 2012.*

## Alte Din

There is now an OFL-licensed, completely free/libre version of DIN called [Alte DIN](http://www.1001fonts.com/alte-din-1451-mittelschrift-font.html).

This is legal because DIN 1451 is a product of the German government, and so is  in the public domain -- only the individual interpretations of it by various font foundries are protected and copyrighted.  Thankfully Peter Weigel traced it for us!

## D-DIN

A corporation called 'Datto' commissioned Monotype creative type director Charles Nix<sup>[[1](https://fonts.playbeing.com/)]</sup> to create a DIN-like font which was released in 2018 under the SIL OFL 1.1.

As of 2021, it is no longer available on their website, but you can find it on a reputable site like [FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/d-din) or [GitHub](https://github.com/openstreetmap/stateofthemap-2019/tree/master/fonts/D-Din). "Altinn" ([Github](https://github.com/Altinn/altinn-din)) is a fork of this project on Github.  "Dinish" ([Website](https://fonts.playbeing.com/))([Github](https://github.com/playbeing/dinish/)) is a fork of this project with continued development, which has also been submitted to Google Fonts.

## Original answer (2012):

I don't know how close you need to come to the DIN typeface, but I found a couple possibles on Google Web Fonts. Using the letters `aGgQqlJ` to narrow down the letter shape matches, I found:

Wire One - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Wire+One

The lowercase letter shapes are quite similar. The overall font is a bit more more condensed than DIN and some of the capital letter shapes are different.

Abel - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Abel

Also, not an exact match but the feel is quite similar.

Comment: None of these come close.

Comment: Subsequently:  Alte DIN is very good.   Adding a link to 'D-DIN' (released 2018 under the SIL OFL).

Comment: It's unfortunate these free Peter Wiegel versions came out just late enough to have missed DIN's spike in popularity ;-)

Answer (score 7):

There's an open source DIN-inspired font called [Gidole](https://gidole.github.io/):

[image: Gidole]

Answer (score 6):

[Cabin](http://www.impallari.com/cabin) is a pretty good free alternative to DIN.  Well, it may be fairly different in design but bear with me - sometimes it can feel as if it is similar:

DIN:

[image: DIN 1451]

Cabin:

[image: Cabin]

[Dosis](http://www.impallari.com/dosis/) is a pretty good free alternative to [FF DIN Round](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/din-round-pro/) if you were interested in a rounded version.

Also, [League Gothic](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/league-gothic) could be a decent alternative to [DIN Engschrift](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/din-schriften/engschrift/) (ie DIN "compressed") though it has slightly less of a "German" feel to it.

Comment: I'm so sad that these nice fonts like Cabin do not support Hungarian language. (DIN has a CE version which includes Hungarian accented characters)

Comment: Dosis is an excellent match. The "v" of the "M" is a little higher in Dosis but otherwise a very decent alternative and superior to all the other answers thus far. This should be selected as the correct answer.

Comment: The middle leg of "E" is shorter in Dosis too however the variation of the M and E combined with the subtle roundedness of Dosis makes for one of the rare cases where font substitution is an improvement on the original. Lowercase matches very decently too.

Comment: the `r` in the Turnstile font screenshot above is quite hideous, imho.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to Windows fonts, the recently announced [Bahnschrift](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/08/23/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16273-pc/) looks to be Microsoft's interpretation of the DIN outlines. In some time it will be available on many computers running Windows and could well be a good, free and close representation of what paid DIN fonts offer.

> Our new first OpenType Variable Font Bahnschrift is now included in builds. This new font industry standard enables us to pack an entire typeface family into a single file with infinite variability. No longer are you constrained to simple weights like Light, Regular, and Bold. Now you can have an infinite range of font styles, with smooth interpolation from Light to Bold and beyond. Better still: because a single, efficient variable font can replace several static fonts, variable fonts save a lot of space.

Comment: is Bahnschrift free for commercial use, namely to include in a mobile app..?

Comment: I don't know, but if you find out, feel free to share! I'm not optimistic, if your mobile app will also debut on iOS, since XCode runs on macOS and as stated, the font licence comes with Windows. Might be incompatible.

Comment: There is currently (2020) a problem with Bahnschrift as provided in Windows 10 where the wrong width will be printed, especially in PDF.   This issue has been reported in multiple places -- [Sketchup](https://forums.sketchup.com/t/bahnschrift-font-display-problem-in-pdf-files/81190); [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/lose-font-bahnschrift-semibold-condensed-when-i/a1c0c306-61ef-4a54-b040-17d9311d8144).

Answer (score 3):

Try Gesta from Typekit. I's very similar. https://typekit.com/fonts/gesta

Comment: Not really. Many stylistic nuances that differ. Dosis is a much better recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bolder version inspired by DIN:

ROPA SANS - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ropa+Sans

Answer (score 1):

I like **Gesta** as a stand-in for DIN. It's not actually all that similar (Gesta is more stylized) but the x-height and overall mood seem to match very well.

http://r-typography.com/gesta.html
*(webfont on Typekit)*

John's suggestion of **Abel** seems good, too. I haven't compared the fonts very closely, but it's got a DIN feel to it at non-display text sizes with a character width sitting somewhere between Engschrift and Mittelschrift.

http://www.madtype.com/tag/abel/
*(webfont on Google Web Fonts)*

Answer (score 1):

TRY roboto .It looks almost like DIN and it comes in so many styles .
Its feels really premium.
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto

Comment: As good and increasingly popular Roboto is, Dosis is still superior in terms of Google fonts.

Answer (score 1):

"Oswald" font is a pretty good alternative. It's a google web font, so it's the best possibility for websites ;-)

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Oswald

Comment: Do you mind posting a screenshot and link?

Comment: this is what i went with

Answer (score 0):

I have used Babel Sans as an alternative to DIN:
http://www.dafont.com/babel-sans.font

Although it is bit thin.

Comment: Babel Sans is pretty much Arial Narrow, with a few modified figures.

Comment: The right leg on "R" is a but too stylistic and the "v" of the "M" is too low. By far, not the worst of the matches suggested to this question however.

Answer (score 0):

**Titillium Web** is also a free alternative:
http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Titillium+Web

DIN Next from Linotype would be the commercial version with webfonts available:
http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/din-next/

Comment: Titillium Web is nowhere close when dealing in uppercase.